# Set a custom HTTP header for a single request using AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I use `AFHTTPSessionManager` to make requests to my webservice. When setting up the manager, I populate the usual headers that all requests will have (including `setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:password`, but for one request only, I have to pass a custom header. This header will also change each time the request is made. For now I just set the header and clear it on completion. Is there a better way?

```
            [self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:signature forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Signature"];

            [self.sessionManager GET:@"path" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
            {
                [self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Signature"];
            }
            failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
            {
                [self.sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-TMA-Signature"];
            }];
```

Comment: `GET` / `POST` / et al. are just convenience methods for creating a request, creating a task and starting it. If you need to customize the request being made, use `dataTaskForRequest:...` instead.

Comment: @mattt thanks, could you expand a bit more? I ended up with this: http://hastebin.com/yemoninaku.m, i.e copying a bunch of code in order to add the header fields in `dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:...`. I can see `dataTaskWithRequest:...` is called here so maybe that's almost what you were advising to do? I'm just worried about the duplicated code